# One filter multiple columns SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

how can I create a single filter in SSRS with multiple columns? Below is an example of a table I am currently using.

```
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri  
-------------------
UK  SA  BG DE USA  
FR  SP  DE US NG  
US  UK  BG CA AU
```

Thank you

Comment: the question is not very clear.. what do you want to filter? Do you want to display the data the way you have shown? Did you want to filter just by country or by week day as well.. what does your dataset look like?

Comment: Hi Harry, my dataset look like the above table but I want to create one filter called "Location" that will use the values from those columns above e.g. (Mon, Tue, Wed) . Basically passing multiple values to one parameter.  

I have tried using an expression like below but didnt work

Expression: =(Fields!Mon.Value = Parameters!Location.Value) or (Fields!Tue.Value  
 = Parameters!Location.Value) or (Fields!Wed.Value = Parameters!Location.Value)  

Operator: =  

Value: =Parameters!Location.Value  

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched for multi value parameter on SO? There are heaps of answers out there for this.